# PySide : "Dynamic" positionning of buttons on GUI?

Tags: python, pyside

I'm using python 2.7.5 on OSX 10.8. I'm learning PySide and trying to build a simple GUI.

I managed to use buttons (WOAAA!) used to chose a path or execute functions :

```
pathBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("FITS file path", self)
pathBtn.setToolTip('Choose the <b>path</b> to your FITS file')
pathBtn.clicked.connect(essai)
pathBtn.resize(pathBtn.sizeHint())
pathBtn.move(200, 100)
```

My problem is, when the program is running and I change the size of the window with the mouse cursor, the buttons don't move, don't adapt to the size variation.

I tried to find some answer (hell yeah google) and I understand that "QVBoxLayout" should do what I want (some kind of "dynamic" positionning, don't know if there's a specific name for that), but I didn't understand its syntax nor how to use it...

Any help appreciated!

Comment: did you read the documentation for [`QVBoxLayout`](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QVBoxLayout.html)?

Comment: Didn't find this documentation while looking for some help, don't know why... Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt widgets, layouts and the widget's size hints determine how things resize. The general procedure to layout a widget would be (for example):

```
dialog = QDialog()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
label = QLabel('This is a label')
edit = QLineEdit('This is a line edit box')
layout.addWidget(label)
layout.addWidget(edit)
dialog.setLayout(layout)
```

(*I cannot test this code here at work (no Qt/PySide), so consider this "pseudo code" :-)

This results in a dialog widget with a label and an edit box. If you resize the dialog widget, the layout and the resize properties of the widgets ensure that the label and edit box resize appropriately: horizontally both expand maximally, but vertically the edit will keep the same size while the label takes all the remaining space. This is because the resize hint of the edit box says it wants to keep its height (namely, one line of text).

If you do not specify a layout, your widgets (buttons, labels) don't do anything whenr resizing their parent widget, which is what you are observing. Hence, the solution is indeed the QVBoxLayout, use it as I described above.

By the way: for more complicated layouts, you probably want to use the Designer tool provided with Qt: this tool lets you see and test your GUI a priori.